# Set Overlap Percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, set, overlap

Assume the following table structure in a SQL database:

```
Att1   |   Att2   |   Att3   |  Cnt
```

I would like to understand the overlap of Att3 for all Att2 combinations for a given Att1.  For example if I had the following table:

```
123   |   456    |   abc    |  1
123   |   456    |   efg    |  1
123   |   456    |   hij    |  1
123   |   456    |   klm    |  1
123   |   456    |   nop    |  1
123   |   789    |   efg    |  1
123   |   789    |   abc    |  1
123   |   789    |   xyz    |  1
123   |   789    |   nop    |  1
345   |   456    |   abc    |  1
345   |   456    |   efg    |  1
345   |   789    |   abc    |  1
345   |   999    |   efg    |  1
```

I would generate the following output:

```
123   |   456    |   456    |  1.0
123   |   456    |   789    |  .6
123   |   789    |   456    |  .75
123   |   789    |   789    |  1.0
345   |   456    |   456    |  1.0
345   |   456    |   789    |  .5
345   |   456    |   999    |  .5
345   |   789    |   456    |  1.0
345   |   789    |   789    |  1.0 
345   |   789    |   999    |  0
345   |   999    |   456    |  1.0
345   |   999    |   789    |  0  
345   |   999    |   999    |  1.0
```

I understand that this may not be best accomplished using SQL, so I'm happy to hear other alternatives, but SQL is where I currently have the data available.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'overlap'?  Also, what is the Cnt column used for, and what does it represent as a fraction?  Your example is good, except I'm still not sure what the expected output represents.

Comment: For the output.  The first column is Attr1.  The 2nd and 3rd column represent all unique pairs of Attr2 that exist for the given Attr1.  Column 4 is the percentage of times Attr3 exists for the 3rd column Attr2 and 2nd column Attr2 vs. the total unique values for the 2nd column attr2.

Comment: I know it is confusing.  Think of the Attr1 column as a state.  Say New York.  Attr2 is a city and Attr3 are the name of the city councilmen.  I want to know what percentage of overlap every city has with every other city in terms of the names of their city councilmen.

Comment: Put further it should be trivial for me to answer the following question from the result set.  In the state of New York what percentage of councilmen in Buffalo have the same name as councilmen in Albany.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a few simple tricks with aggregates:

```
SELECT t1.att1, t1.att2, t2.att2 as att2_other, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.att3 = t1.att3 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(DISTINCT t1.att3) as Cnt
FROM table_name t1
JOIN table_name t2
  ON t1.att1 = t2.att1
GROUP BY t1.att1, t1.att2, t2.att2
```

Working sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1bd8/3)